# Convert Mysql query to Mongodb query

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I want to convert the following query in MySQL to MongoDB . Need help .

```
  SELECT customerName,city,state FROM customers 
  WHERE creditLimit > (SELECT AVG(creditLimit) FROM customers )
```

Comment: what is `creditLimit` field? Array or integer or string?

Comment: @goonernike can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: creditLimit is a integer column

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
db.customers.find( { "creditLimit": { $gt: { $avg: $creditLimit } } }, { "customerName": 1, "city": 1, "state": 1 } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
db.customers.aggregate([
  { $match : {
    "creditLimit": { $gt: {$avg: "creditLimit"} }
  } },
  { $group: {
    customerName:'$customerName',
    city: '$city',
    state: '$state'
  } }
]);
```